# What is the fastest BitTorrent client?

Tags: file-sharing, bittorrent, download-manager

Does anyone know which BitTorrent client gives you the fastest download rates?

For eg: I came across [BitTyrant](http://bittyrant.cs.washington.edu/) which claims its 70% faster than most.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Its a perfectly helpful power-user question.

Comment: Since BitTorrent also has quite a few legal uses, I just wonder why this Q got so many downvotes.

Comment: Rule of thumb. If you are going to use the words "Best Of", "Must Have", "Which is better?", "Faster" then the question is subjective, a discussion and should be flagged CW from the beginning.

Comment: Most of the time it boils down to properly configuring the client to make the most of your bandwidth supplied by your ISP, Azureus 2.5.0.4 is one of my favorites. If it is a slow torrent with limited peers that have low bandwidth, it will be slow, not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can only speak from personal experience, but several years ago I tried several clients, (eg the one built in Opera, Azureus, Bitcomet, uTorrent and one or two others that I can't remember).

Now upload/download speed quickly became a non issue for me, as none of these clients appeared to me to be significantly faster or slower than the others. It is impossible to be sure as there are so many other factors (eg the speed of your connection,  how many seeds are available and what connection they have and where they are based etc), so it is not accurate to simply repeat a download using a different client to see if it is faster or slower.

However what was obvious was there was quite a difference in speed of use between the clients. Some of them were extremely sluggish and memory hogs (possibly with memory leaks) which affected use, so this quickly became my main concern.

So, now if I need to use a client, I just use uTorrent, which is small,fast and efficient and I like the user interface.

I remember reading about BitTryant a year or two back, but not much since. The sceptic in me would say that if it really was 70% faster than the rest in real-life situations, then I would expect it to have had a bigger effect. (So either the technology has migrated to other clients since then, or else it was yet another theoretical improvement which didn't translate to real-life.)

All IMHO.

Answer (score 13):

They' re all pretty much the same. I think you're more limited by your download speed than by the speed of the bittorrent app.

However, [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) has a very low resource consumption. I highly recommend it.

Comment: I can make guesses too. I was looking for someone who knew the answer to this.

Comment: Wow, that was a mean comment! The next time you don't agree with my answer, downvote me and that's that.

Comment: Guess I have no choice but to accept the only.

Comment: Why didn't you wait for another answer? Try leaving your question open, there are going to be other opinions. I'm not after the reputation points, I just want to help. I was actually considering removing my answer after your first comment.

Comment: Wow, you're right, and there's another Alex who's interested in sharing his info too!

Answer (score 6):

Your network connection will be your biggest bottleneck. Your ISP will determine your up/downstream speeds and some ISP's are throttling the Internet connections of users who use software like BitTorrent or other streaming software.

Also keep in mind that the upstream speed of the other systems that you connect to are important too! It's great if you have a 1 Terabit network connection but when you're using any BitTorrent product to collect a file and this file originates from someone with a 56K6 connection, you still have to wait a long, long time...

You might prefer to just choose the right software based on it's additional features instead of just network speed.

Comment: Nice answer! I also think the network connection is the biggest bottleneck he's going to have.

Answer (score 2):

[BitComet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitComet). If downloading music, choose what you want. If 1.2 GB file you choose what you want, uncheck any unwanted file, and it shrinks it. Download BitComet. Make no changes no matter your download speed, and it will be 100% faster.

Comment: Remove the email, speak in good clear english, and why not capitalize the words that should be. KTHNXBAI

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the most out of your bandwidth I would suggest setting your bandwidth allocation (in bittorrent) to high, if your upload speed seems to have an effect on your download I would suggest limiting the upload speed temporarily, and once completed reallocate your bandwidth accordingly. The fastest client in terms of network speed is subjective due to the fact that they all employ the bit torrent protocol. so they all use your network about the same. Your knowledge of how to optimize whatever client you use will be the deciding factor. So it's up to you to find one your comfortable with and understand. I use Bittorrent because it's been around for a while and is configurable in many ways. However U torrent performs just as well. Low RAM use U torrent A ton of RAM Maybe something jazzed up like Azeurus. I hope this helped in your quest for knowledge.